# How to capture Network traffic on windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a network monitor or wireshark like tool available? Kindly provide links to any blogs/articles etc. if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following shows how to use Fiddler and the Windows Phone 7 emulator:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx

**Update**
To capture traffic on an actual device is a bit more work:
 - You need a machine running foddler and set up to act as a proxy (Tools > Fiddler options > Connections)
 - Set the port to list on and check 'Allow remote computers to connect'
 - Create an adhoc wireless network from that machine (this assumes you are using a machine which can do this)
 - Connect to the new adhoc network from your device
 - Voila! You can now see the traffic going through fiddler

Comment: I want to do it on the actual device. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does this also work for network traffic from an application (say using the Live Connect SDK) rather than a browser application?

Comment: @PhilippSchmid yes works for all HTTP traffic from a device (assuming standard ports are used)

Answer (score 0):

Proxy does not work on WP 7 device when it's connected to PC. Need to change Zune settings:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Zune\WindowsPhone]
    "DTPTAllowed"=dword:0
```